# Create Empty Project for Project

Tags: visual-studio-2019, blazor

Hi I just upgraded to Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview

VS Community 2019 Preview version 16.2.0 Preview 3.0

a) I did the following:

follow this link for instruction to install below 1,2,3:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

for .netcore SDK and .netCore runtime :

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0

1) SDK 3.0.100-preview6-012264

for Runtime

2) runtime 3.0,0-preview6-27804-01

3) Install Blazor Extension

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aspnet.blazor

b) Create Blazor app using

Use Blazor (Asp.net core Hosted). After selected this template, no blazor project is shown as below:
Note: If I have not install Blazor Extension, I wont have this template show up.

Please help to solve this issue.

Anyway to use CMD prompt to check each of the required component like Blazor Extension and others?

[image]

Update: 
 I did dotnet --info  and i got below info. I did install above 1,2,and 3 
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.829]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>dotnet --info
  It was not possible to find any installed dotnet SDKs
  Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.0.0-preview6-27804-01
  Commit:  fdf81c6faf

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0-preview6.19307.2 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.6 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.5 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0-preview6-27804-01 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Thanks

Comment: Please explain which project template you chose, and confirm that you installed the Blazor extension?

Comment: @Mister Magoo, please see my update for installation and creating Blazor App. Thanks

Comment: Does the same happen for every Blazor template or just that one?

Comment: every time when I create Blazor App, the end result is empty blazor project just like the Image I showed above. I tried more than 3 times already.

Comment: Sounds like you might need to uninstall and reinstall to me

Comment: Did you nstall the ASP Core workload?  What happens when you create a non-Blazor web app?

Comment: @ Henk Holterman,  It is the same for non-blazor app, I did asp.net Web Api or use the API template and I got empty project in return. What's wrong?  What I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the issue or the problem. The steps above are correct.  For my computer, I need to download the x86 .netcore SDK. previously, I downloaded x64 .netcore sdk and it did not work for me.

Thanks